# Facebook Mutual Likes API request returns only the count

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the mutual Likes using Facebook Graph API V2.0, But it returns only the count.. here is the output I got..

API URL : https://graph.facebook.com/876378047155445?fields=context.fields(mutual_likes)&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Output:
`{
    "context": {
    "mutual_likes": {
    "data": [     ],
     "summary": {
     "total_count": 4
     }
     }
   },
   "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
}`

Please suggest some solution...

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: any idea why you're not getting it, i'm stuck at same problem

Answer (score 1):

I too experienced this problem and I think it's a bug in Facebook's API. The solution I used was to use this endpoint "/{user-id}?fields=context" as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/social-context/v2.0#user-context, which is not bugged! It will return both the mutual_friends and mutual_likes simultaneously however, and not just specifically the mutual_likes.

EDIT:

It seems like I was totally wrong, and it is not a bug with the facebook API. You can only see the mutual friends and mutual interests if the users are already friends unless you provide "appsecret_proof". According to facebook documentation:

"If you want to call this endpoint on behalf two app-users who are not friends, then you must provide the appsecret_proof parameter along with the user access token when making the request. This means you must call this endpoint from your server." -https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user.context/mutual_friends

The thing is they only documented this in the mutual_friends doc, but not the mutual likes document here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user.context/mutual_likes, which I've tested and requires the users to be friends before receiving the data about the mutual likes.

To fix this you can either go on the facebook app and disable the requirement of appsecret_proof (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests#appsecret_proof) or have to call this api request server sided.

Comment: It seems like the "context.fields(mutual_likes)"endpoint works again. Either they have fixed it, or is just an unreliable end point.

Comment: Unfortunately using the `appsecret_proof` didn't help me much. Same "inconsistent" results.

Answer (score 0):

For you to get the actual Likes in the data array, both users need to grant the "user_likes" permission. Otherwise, you will only get the count. This allows you to evaluate shared interests quantitatively while protecting the users' privacy.